# Should I namespace functions and classes?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading through some global scare articles, you can thank Crockford for this question.

For instance, I have a function I've defined as:

```
function httpRequest() {}
```

This is a pretty generic function name, which *could* potentially be used in a thirdparty library. Should I just make it a habit to attach the function to an app namespace?

```
APPNAME.httpRequest() {}
```

I read through Google's style guide for JavaScript and they recommended this for variables, what about functions and classes?

```
APPNAME.MyClass = (function () {
  'use strict';

  function MyClass() {}

  MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {};

  return MyClass;
}());
```

EDIT:
Let's say I plan on combining with a lot of other libraries.

Comment: please elaborate on `some global scare articles` - any sources ?

Comment: global variables are bad, there are too many articles

Comment: Ok fair enough, gotcha

Comment: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/04/16/global-domination-part-two/. I see a lot of libraries on github wrapping everything in an app namespace.

Comment: Next thing, you'll be namespacing your namespace with a GUID because *you never know* someone might use the same namespace as you.

Comment: There's no one answer to this question -- it's an opinion-based issue depending on whether you expect to be combining this with other Javascript, etc.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you never know, you never know :P

Comment: @sphanley let's say I am planning on combining

Comment: Then you should make a decision! I don't know what you expect people to say -- some people do code this way, some people don't, and there's no right answer.

Comment: @user3448187 naa, you should just use modules - that way your variables are closure scoped. Look into RequireJS and browserify

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum modules are for variables and functions, what about a generic function like httpRequest which doesn't really belong to a specific module. or do you mean APPNAME?

Comment: @user3448187 put those in a module - for example the functions making http requests can be put in an http module.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Even if there's only one function in the module? :P

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Do you want to write an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript variables are closure scoped. So you can always use an IIFE to encapsulate them:

```
(function(){
    function httpRequest() { /* */ }
    httpRequest(...);
})()

//httpRequest is not defined here unless it was defined above the block
```

You can also export stuff to the global namespace

```
var httpUtils = (function(){

    return whatever; // whatever is exported, the other variables are internal
})()
```

Creating objects that encapsulate behavior like this and exposes some is called a module pattern.

You can use module loaders to manage your modules. One example is [RequireJS.](http://requirejs.org/)

```
require(["httpUtils","logger",function(http,log){
    http.request(...); // uses from other module
    log(..); // use other module
    return { }; // the return values can be used in other modules, require by file name
                // or explicit configuration
});
```

Namespacing is also an option, but it is generally less desirable.

Comment: what if I only have on httpRequest method though, should I still make a module httpUtils? I'm reading some module articles right now XD

Comment: @user3448187 httpRequest seems like a giant method if that's the only HTTP method you have, however if it is indeed the _only_ method you have and it doesn't belong logically anywhere else (like a REST module etc) I'd put it in its own file (module in this case)

Comment: very interesting, I'll continue reading up on this, thanks for all your help!

Comment: probably you want to include an example with arguments for your examples. Functions without arguments are the exceptions

Comment: @Toskan the `(...)` is supposed to symbolize arguments :)

Comment: that was not what I was asking for. Your second code example, let's say I want to use `httpUtils("hello world");` imho this is a bad example of yours (beside of the quesitonmark towards arguments), since this is the place where you should always use a namespace. `httpUtils` is certainly taken by someone.